# Type representing a tuple type with the keys of an object as string literals

Tags: typescript

Given an interface:

```
interface EPostageInsertExEvent_Parameter {
    readonly Doc: Word.Document;
    cpDeliveryAddrStart: number;
    cpDeliveryAddrEnd: number;
    readonly cpReturnAddrStart: number,
    readonly cpReturnAddrEnd: number;
    readonly xaWidth: number;
    readonly yaHeight: number;
    readonly bstrPrinterName: string;
    readonly bstrPaperFeed: string;
    readonly fPrint: boolean;
    fCancel: boolean;
}
```

how can I define a tuple type consisting of the keys of that interface as string literals? In other words, the equivalent of the following:

```
type EPostageInsertExEvent_ArgNames = ['Doc', 'cpDeliveryAddrStart', 'cpDeliveryAddrEnd',
    'cpReturnAddrStart', 'cpReturnAddrEnd', 'xaWidth', 'yaHeight', 'bstrPrinterName',
    'bstrPaperFeed', 'fPrint', 'fCancel'];
```

Comment: You want a tuple or a string array? You want it at design or runtime?

Comment: @RodrigoPedrosa The type should be a tuple type, composed of string literals. I want it at design time.

Comment: I think you did it already in your question.

Comment: @RodrigoPedrosa, the idea is not to write it out yourself.  See my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not currently possible in TypeScript.  There is an [feature request](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13298) in GitHub which would allow this, but there hasn't been much movement there.  (You might want to go and give it a  and describe your use case, or you might not.)  TypeScript doesn't yet have extensive support for type functions.  Right now the closest you can get is:

```
type EPostageInsertExEvent_ArgNames = Array<keyof EPostageInsertExEvent_Parameter>;
```

but that does not guarantee anything about the presence, uniqueness, or order of the keys.  Sorry not to have better news.